# Can I raise the point limit on a geospatial map in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I have a csv with approx. 108,000 rows, each of which is a unique long/lat combination. The file is uploaded into S3 and visualised in Quicksight.

My problem is that Quicksight is only showing the first 10,000 points. The points that it shows are in the correct place, the map works perfectly, it's just missing 90%+ of the points I wish to show. I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using an admin enabled role for both S3 and Quicksight as this is a Dev environment.

Is there a way to increase this limit so that I can show all of my data points?

I have looked in the visualisation settings (the drop doen in the viz) and explored the tab on the left as much as I can. I am quite new to AWS so this may be a really easy one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider combining lat/lng that are near each other based on some rule you come up when preparing your data.

There appears to be limitations on how many rows and columns you can serve to QuickSight:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/data-source-limits.html

Comment: I did consider summarising, but unfortunately each point needs to be where it is (each one represents a street light location).

There are indeed row limits, but it's 100,000,000 and I have 108,000 rows so that's not it either.

Comment: If it's stopping at exactly 10,000 then there has to be a limitation being enforced. I mean, its likely, because why 10,000? I didn't see anything either in the docs about 10,000 but am curious as to why in any event. Otherwise I would look at the data itself to see if there are any inconsistencies, like a comma out of place. Even still why would that break at exactly 10,000 so not likely the problem.